# does a Firebase instance DecodedIdToken have custom claims?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

We can get a user's custom claims in the front-end like so:

```
const { claims } = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
```

However, in Cloud Functions, every callable Cloud Function has a context:

```
context: functions.https.CallableContext
```

With this we can access the "user token" of the requesting user like so:

```
context.auth.token
```

This token is a [DecodedIdToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.DecodedIdToken) (see link for reference docs)

However, I wonder if I can access that user's custom claims on this `DecodedIdToken` like so:

```
const { claims } = context.auth.token
```

Because the documentation says nothing about the custom claims...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I read the documentation, it I would assume that it contains custom claims.  Look at its "indexable" feature:

> Indexable
>
> ```
> [key: string]: any
> ```
>
> Interface representing a decoded Firebase ID token, returned from the
>   verifyIdToken() method.

That `[key: string]: any` is TypeScript for saying that it supports general string lookups, in addition to the specific properties detailed individually.  This suggests that you should be able to find other items in the object that are (likely) custom claims.

It's also plainly saying that it's the same as the value returned by [verifyIdToken()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#verifyidtoken), which is how you get custom claims when working with the Admin SDK.  So, I suggest just trying it.  If it doesn't work the way you expect, [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: I'll try and let you know here

Comment: to my findings it doesn't have the custom claims, and a separate API call needs to be made just for those. Please integrate this in your answer if you can!